# Android phone and Bluetooth module sepecificatoin

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am quite new with Bluetooth communication using Android. I want to develop a sample project that is to ON and OFF different LEDs via Bluetooth by using Android phone, for this I would need a Bluetooth module to communicate with the LEDs.

Now my questions are:

1)    What technical specification are required for Bluetooth module to communicate with android phones(I have two android phones having Bluetooth version V2.1 and V3.0)?

2)    which company's Bluetooth module would be better for me in the above situation?

Please help me in this respect I would be very thankful to you for this act of kindness. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used this http://www.rhydolabz.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=479 for my project and its pretty good

Comment: Dear! could you tell me that what specific docuements I need to study for android side programming to communicate with rhydolabz's bluetooth device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Use the UUID specified there for SPP

The bluetooth adapter will work as a Server by default.So you should do Client programming on android side.

My project deals with sending data continuously,so I had to use HandlerThreads so that I don't block the UIThread.Since you don't need to send much data you can work directly on UIThread.So  [connecting as a client section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) of android documentation will do.